# Не приходят письма на gmail из собственного домена

Tags: gmail, exim

От домена нашей организации не доходят письма на почтовый домен gmail.com.

Используется Centos 6 Exim .

В доменной зоне прописаны dmarc, spf и DKIM
при проверки на g-suite все хорошо ошибок нет.
nslookup тоже отображает txt записи доменной зоны
А при попытке отправить на gmail:

```
    This message was created automatically by mail delivery software. A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  xxxx@gmail.com
    host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [x.x.x.x]
    SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined end of data:
    550-5.7.1 [x.x.x.x       1] Our system has detected an unusual rate of
    550-5.7.1 unsolicited mail originating from your IP address. To protect our
    550-5.7.1 users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has been blocked.
    550-5.7.1 Please visit
    550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedIPError to review our
    550 5.7.1 Bulk Email Senders Guidelines. o15si15716986lji.200 - gsmtp




Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;xxxx@gmail.com
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 [x.x.x.x       1] Our system has detected an unusual rate of
 550-5.7.1 unsolicited mail originating from your IP address. To protect our
 550-5.7.1 users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has been blocked.
 550-5.7.1 Please visit
 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedIPError to review our
 550 5.7.1 Bulk Email Senders Guidelines. o15si15716986lji.200 - gsmtp
```

Еще и отчет Dmarc:

```
  <feedback>
<report_metadata>
<org_name>google.com</org_name>
<email>noreply-dmarc-support@google.com</email>
<extra_contact_info>https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580</extra_contact_info>
<report_id>18067631424851096474</report_id>
<date_range>
<begin>1570838400</begin>
<end>1570924799</end>
</date_range>
</report_metadata>
<policy_published>
<domain></domain>
<adkim>r</adkim>
<aspf>r</aspf>
<p>reject</p>
<sp>reject</sp>
<pct>100</pct>
</policy_published>
<record>
<row>
<source_ip></source_ip>
<count>4</count>
<policy_evaluated>
<disposition>none</disposition>
<dkim>pass</dkim>
<spf>pass</spf>
</policy_evaluated>
</row>
<identifiers>
<header_from></header_from>
</identifiers>
<auth_results>
<dkim>
<domain></domain>
<result>pass</result>
<selector>dkim</selector>
</dkim>
<spf>
<domain></domain>
<result>pass</result>
</spf>
</auth_results>
</record>
</feedback>
```

Домен на ошибки проверял на сайте  mxtoolbox.com ошибок нет, ptr запись есть, отправляю письмо без спец символов. Причем на яндекс письма приходят спокойно, да и есть второй домен с которого письма на google идут без проблем с идентичными настройками exim.

Проверка FCrDNS Test и DNSBL lookups:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не поможет. IP заблокирован гуглом.

Comment: Указанную ссылку-то читали?

Comment: Конечно читал иначе бы не писал про DKIM SPF и
проверял сайт состоит ли он  в черном списке

Comment: Что, например, про ваш адрес думают разные DNSBL'ы? Впрочем, это не повлияет на гугль в любом случае. Поднимайте smarthost где-нибудь в облаке и шлите исходящую через него.

Comment: по поводу DNSBL: ip не перечислены в SBL
ip  не перечислены в PBL
ip не перечислены в XBL
Спасибо за совет !